# project 3D plot to 2D screen plane

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, projection

I have got the following in Matlab (solution as in the example in http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/viewmtx.html):

[image]

```
subplot(211)
h = ezplot3('cos(t)', 'sin(t)', 'sin(5*t)', [-pi pi]);
data = get(h,{'XData','YData','Zdata'});
data = [cat(1,data{:})', ones(numel(data{1}),1)];

% Projection matrix on screen
[az,el] = view(); A = viewmtx(az,el);
data_transformed = A*data';

subplot(212)
plot(data_transformed(1,:), data_transformed(2,:))
```

That transformation does not work with:

```
h = ezplot3('t', 'sin(t)', '20*cos(t)', [0 10*pi]);
```

[image]

## How to get the screen projection of the 3rd plot?

Also, any links to the math behind the projection, with examples would be nice too :)

Comment: Isn't the fourth plot just the view in the [x,z] plane of the third plot?

Comment: @Adriaan It shouldn't be. First plot applies same transformation matrix and gets the screen projection (or this is what I thought it does).

Comment: I think they should. As far as I can see you are not altering the plotted function, just the angle at which it is viewed. The second image is again just a [x,z] plane view of the first one. You could do this by hand (click the 'rotate' icon on the plot), but this code apparently rotates the plot for you

Comment: Well, I need the screen projection (in 2D) of the third plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to normalize by the `DataAspectRatio`, so the viewTransform matrix becomes:

```
[az, el] = view(gca);
A = viewmtx(az,el) * makehgtform('scale',1./get(gca,'DataAspectRatio'));
```

The full answer can be seen on http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/248362-screen-2d-projection-of-3d-plot

Answer (score 0):

The projection depends on `view`. If you try with various `view` values, the project in 2D will produce different results.

For example, `[az,el]=view(60,30);` and you will have this projection.

[image]

and `[az,el]=view(30,15);` you will have this image

[image]

Comment: I changed the question since it previously did not convey what I wanted. Hence your answer, although contextual, does not solve my problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.